# Why doesn't Python throw a ValueError when you use a negative range in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I was wondering why this doesn't throw a ValueError:

```
>>>    for i in range(-1):
...        print "something"
...
>>>
```

Is there any use for this negative argument used in this way?

Comment: `range(-1)` is an empty list. You *can* iterate an empty list but it won't loop at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range can accept a negative step, too

```
In [2]: list(range(0, -10, -1))
Out[2]: [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

Not to mention positively-stepping ranges of negative numbers.

```
In [3]: list(range(-9, 1))
Out[3]: [-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0]
```

As for why it doesn't throw an error on the one negative argument version, I think it's just a case of the Zen

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `range` function starts at 0. Additionally, the step is positive 1 by default. You are providing only a single argument to the function (the stopping point), and that argument is `-1`. Thus, it is trying to **increment** from 0 to -1.

See the documentation on [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

> If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0.

If you wish to go negative, you need to include `start`, `stop` and `step` values:

```
range(0, -10, -1)
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

There is no exception thrown, because it is behaving as the documentation describes.